# Can't connect to Google Earth Pro with Proxy

Tags: proxy, google-earth

i'm using Google Earth Pro version 7.3.4.8573 (latest) on Windows 10 with a proxy connection.
Once launched, the app doesn't ask the proxy credential, and i can't neither access the kh.google.com server clicking on file > server sign in.
I've tried also to add a specific permission on Windows firewall for the exe file, but still not connecting.
Thanks for attention.

Comment: Applications must explicitly support proxy credentials. It is possible Google Earth Pro doesn’t.